# How to combine tables with different rowcount in specific result layout

Tags: php, mysql

I searched the internet and this forum, but can't find the right answer. I'm trying to JOIN different tables (Locations, Sensors, SensorRawData) and looking for a specific output.

I tried GROUP_CONCAT combined with JOIN ect. but none gave me the result I need.

To show the tables and example query I created a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3e889/14

With only joins it is not possible, but using Group_concat or UNION is not giving me the solutions i want.

```
SELECT Location, SensorName, TrafficShaper, TrafficIN, TrafficOut, Outage
FROM Locations
JOIN Sensors ON Sensors.LocationsID = Locations.ID
JOIN SensorRawData ON SensorRawData.SensorID = Sensors.SensorID
WHERE SensorRawData.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59'
ORDER BY Location, Sensors.Queue
```

The output I'm looking for should be like (sorry can't use pictures yet, so its a url)

[image: https://www.quotify.nl/Knipsel.PNG]

So, aligned horizontally with first the Location and then the five Queue's in order of the Location and Queue (ORDER BY Location, Sensors.Queue). Within the Queue's I need the highest TrafficIN and the highest TrafficOut value between the selected datetime.

How?

Comment: Can there be more than 5 queues?

Comment: what you want exactly i am bit confused

Comment: @Tom I want to join the tables so, that i can get the output as i mentioned. There is another possibility to create 3 different queries. But that's not the way it should go.

Comment: @nick, for now there are only 5 queue's but in the future there can be more.

Comment: @Marvin the query I've written will work for 5 queues. It can be expanded for more, but you might want to consider a stored procedure in that case. Unfortunately MySQL does not directly support pivot tables such as this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for editing my post and change the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no more than the 5 sensor queues in your sample data, you can use conditional aggregation to get the results you want:

```
SELECT Location,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 1' THEN TrafficIN END) AS `Queue 1 IN`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 1' THEN TrafficOut END) AS `Queue 1 Out`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 2' THEN TrafficIN END) AS `Queue 2 IN`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 2' THEN TrafficOut END) AS `Queue 2 Out`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 3' THEN TrafficIN END) AS `Queue 3 IN`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 3' THEN TrafficOut END) AS `Queue 3 Out`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 4' THEN TrafficIN END) AS `Queue 4 IN`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 4' THEN TrafficOut END) AS `Queue 4 Out`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 5' THEN TrafficIN END) AS `Queue 5 IN`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 5' THEN TrafficOut END) AS `Queue 5 Out`
FROM Locations l
LEFT JOIN Sensors s ON s.LocationsID = l.ID
LEFT JOIN SensorRawData r ON r.SensorID = s.SensorID
                         AND r.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2019-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59'
GROUP BY Location
```

Output is the raw data as shown in your image; it is probably easiest to change the display format in your application.

I've updated your [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3e889/30) to show the results.

Comment: One more question about this solution, how can I also select the TrafficShaper for the Queue/Sensor?

Comment: @Marvin I've updated the demo again to give the shaper values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3e889/49

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way to get the data, using a crosstab query:

```
SELECT `Location`,
CONCAT("Queue 1 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 1', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 1', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),")") AS `Queue 1`,
CONCAT("Queue 2 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 2', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 2', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),")") AS `Queue 2`,
CONCAT("Queue 3 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 3', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 3', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),")") AS `Queue 3`,
CONCAT("Queue 4 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 4', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 4', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),")") AS `Queue 4`,
CONCAT("Queue 5 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 5', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 5', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),")") AS `Queue 5`
FROM `Locations` 
JOIN `Sensors` ON `Sensors`.`LocationsID` = `Locations`.`ID`
JOIN `SensorRawData` ON `SensorRawData`.`SensorID` = `Sensors`.`SensorID`
WHERE `SensorRawData`.`TimeStamp` BETWEEN '2019-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59'
-- ORDER BY `Locations`.`Location`, `Sensors`.`Queue`
GROUP BY `Locations`.`Location`
```

This produces the output:

```
| Location | Queue 1                              | Queue 2                              | Queue 3                              | Queue 4                              | Queue 5                               |
| -------- | ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------- |
| Voorburg | Queue 1 (IN:1.475493 / OUT:1.977284) | Queue 2 (IN:0.272115 / OUT:0.266318) | Queue 3 (IN:0.057073 / OUT:0.044036) | Queue 4 (IN:0.174479 / OUT:7.849057) | Queue 5 (IN:10.067641 / OUT:3.057053) |
```

Using a crosstab may be a bit more complex, but it does allow you to pivot tables in MySQL while giving you the option to use more complex expressions to get the results in a format you desire. For example, I used the `CONCAT()` function to allow me to place inline text with the results. You should be able to do this with the first answer, using the following example:

```
CONCAT("Queue 1 (IN:", MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 1' THEN TrafficIN END), " / OUT:",MAX(CASE WHEN SensorName = 'Queue 1' THEN TrafficOut END),")") AS "",
```

Like I said, just another way to get the data.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3XCuu2X1QmEuVcngp6Wnie/0)

UPDATE: On seeing the comment about the Traffic Shaper I've added to the query to facilitate this:

```
SELECT `Location`,
CONCAT("Queue 1 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 1', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 1', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),") Shaper:", (SELECT `Sensors`.`TrafficShaper` FROM `Sensors` WHERE `Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 1')) AS `Queue 1`,
CONCAT("Queue 2 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 2', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 2', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),") Shaper:", (SELECT `Sensors`.`TrafficShaper` FROM `Sensors` WHERE `Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 2')) AS `Queue 2`,
CONCAT("Queue 3 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 3', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 3', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),") Shaper:", (SELECT `Sensors`.`TrafficShaper` FROM `Sensors` WHERE `Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 3')) AS `Queue 3`,
CONCAT("Queue 4 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 4', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 4', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),") Shaper:", (SELECT `Sensors`.`TrafficShaper` FROM `Sensors` WHERE `Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 4')) AS `Queue 4`,
CONCAT("Queue 5 (IN:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 5', `TrafficIN`, 0)), " / OUT:", MAX(IF(`Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 5', `TrafficOUT`, 0)),") Shaper:", (SELECT `Sensors`.`TrafficShaper` FROM `Sensors` WHERE `Sensors`.`SensorName` = 'Queue 5')) AS `Queue 5`
FROM `Locations` 
JOIN `Sensors` ON `Sensors`.`LocationsID` = `Locations`.`ID`
JOIN `SensorRawData` ON `SensorRawData`.`SensorID` = `Sensors`.`SensorID`
WHERE `SensorRawData`.`TimeStamp` BETWEEN '2019-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-03-13 23:59:59'
-- ORDER BY `Locations`.`Location`, `Sensors`.`Queue`
GROUP BY `Locations`.`Location`
```

This results in the following output:

```
| Location | Queue 1                                          | Queue 2                                          | Queue 3                                          | Queue 4                                          | Queue 5                                           |
| -------- | ------------------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------- |
| Voorburg | Queue 1 (IN:1.475493 / OUT:1.977284) Shaper:2048 | Queue 2 (IN:0.272115 / OUT:0.266318) Shaper:8192 | Queue 3 (IN:0.057073 / OUT:0.044036) Shaper:5120 | Queue 4 (IN:0.174479 / OUT:7.849057) Shaper:2048 | Queue 5 (IN:10.067641 / OUT:3.057053) Shaper:3072 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3XCuu2X1QmEuVcngp6Wnie/1)

Comment: Thanks for giving a second solution!... I will look into it :)